# how to query amazon dynamodb using pentaho

Tags: pentaho, amazon-dynamodb

I have tried to connect amazon dynamodb using pentaho using a generic database connection in pentaho but i'm unable to connect. how to query Amazon dynamodb using pentaho?

Comment: When you say you can't connect, what specific errors are you getting?

Comment: What product from the Pentaho Suite are you using to connect? How did you try with the generic database connection? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm using spoon in pentaho for ETL purpose. I literally don't know how to connect to dynamodb through spoon. I've learnt that its not possible to connect that way(please correct me if wrong). Any idea on how to connect to dynamodb via spoon and query?

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: No DyanmoDBInput or DynamoDBQuery kettle plugins available

My Suggested Solutions:

1. You can write your own kettle plugin using AWS DynamoDB Java SDK
   Bonus:  Contribute it to the community :)
2. You can write a Java class that does what you need and uses AWS DynamoDB SDK.  Build a jar file that has all the dependencies in it.  Drop the jar file into kettle lib directory.
   Then use "User Defined Java Class" plugin, create an instance of your class and pass the parameters from the stream as input to dynamodb query and pass any output & error codes/messages to the stream.

Both these solutions are reusable.  I have used the 2nd solution to connect to other data sources and it works well.

Goodluck.